# How do I render a Next.js page using React Testing Library?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom, jestjs, next.js

I am writing a unit test for Next.js application.

The components side of the 'pages' folder return `'NextPage'`, in typescript, where

NextPage is imported from `'next'`.

For example: `import { NextPage } from 'next';  const BenchmarksPage: NextPage = () => {...`

There are other components inside the 'pages' folder.

These components **do not** return `'NextPage'`, but return `'FC'`, which is imported from 'react'.

For example: `import { FC } from 'react'; const RegisterJWT: FC = (props) => {...`

In my Jest/Testing Library, I render these components like this:

```
render(<Component />)
expect(...)
```

Is this the correct way to render both the NextPage component and FC component?

Only FC components are rendering, but not NextPage components.

When rendering NextPage components, it returns `<body></div></body>`, an empty DOM tree.

EDIT:

Here is a NextPage component, that does not render in test:

```
import {
  Box,
  capitalize,
  Container,
  FormControl,
  InputLabel,
  MenuItem,
  Select,
} from '@material-ui/core';
import { NextPage } from 'next';
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet-async';
import RequireScope from 'src/components/authentication/RequireScope';
import BenchmarkTable from 'src/components/benchmark/BenchmarkTable';
import DashboardLayout from 'src/components/dashboard/DashboardLayout';
import Heading from 'src/components/Heading';
import useSettings from 'src/hooks/useSettings';
import gtm from 'src/lib/gtm';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'src/store';
import { getAllRollingTwelveCalcs } from 'src/store/rolling-twelve/rolling-twelve.thunk';
import { Timeframe, timeframeMap } from 'src/types/benchmark';

const BenchmarksPage: NextPage = () => {
  const { settings } = useSettings();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [selectedTimeframe, setSelectedTimeframe] = useState<Timeframe>(
    Timeframe.Monthly,
  );

  const company = useSelector((state) => state.company.current);

  useEffect(() => {
    gtm.push({ event: 'page_view' });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getAllRollingTwelveCalcs());
  }, [company]);

  const handleTimeframeChange = useCallback(
    (
      event: React.ChangeEvent<{
        name?: string;
        value: Timeframe;
        event: Event | React.SyntheticEvent<Element, Event>;
      }>,
    ) => {
      setSelectedTimeframe(event.target.value);
    },
    [],
  );

  return (
    <RequireScope scopes={['query:benchmark-calcs']}>
      <DashboardLayout>
        <Helmet>
          <title>Benchmarks</title>
        </Helmet>
        <Container maxWidth={settings.compact ? 'xl' : false}>
          <Box
            sx={{
              display: 'flex',
              alignItems: 'flex-end',
              justifyContent: 'space-between',
              mb: 4,
            }}
          >
            <Heading>Benchmarks</Heading>
            <FormControl sx={{ width: 300 }}>
              <InputLabel>Timeframe</InputLabel>
              <Select
                sx={{ background: '#ffffff', maxWidth: 400 }}
                value={selectedTimeframe}
                label="Timeframe"
                onChange={handleTimeframeChange}
              >
                {[...timeframeMap.keys()].map((timeframe) => (
                  <MenuItem key={timeframe} value={timeframe}>
                    {capitalize(timeframe)}
                  </MenuItem>
                ))}
              </Select>
            </FormControl>
          </Box>
          <BenchmarkTable
            timeframe={selectedTimeframe}
            data-testid="benchmark-table"
          />
        </Container>
      </DashboardLayout>
    </RequireScope>
  );
};

export default BenchmarksPage;
```

It uses thunk, which is here:

```
import { createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import axios from 'src/lib/axios';
import { RootState } from 'src/store';
import {
  RollingTwelveAnalysisCategoryCalculation,
  RollingTwelveManualInputLineItemCalculation,
} from 'src/types/rolling-twelve';

export const getAllRollingTwelveCalcs = createAsyncThunk<
  {
    anaylsisCategoryCalcs: RollingTwelveAnalysisCategoryCalculation[];
    manualInputCalcs: RollingTwelveManualInputLineItemCalculation[];
  },
  undefined,
  {
    state: RootState;
  }
>('rollingTwelve/getAll', async () => {
  const response = await axios.get(`/rolling-twelve/all`);
  return response.data;
});
```

Now here is a component, that is 'FC' (not NextPage) that does render. This still is inside pages folder:

```
import { useAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-react';
import {
  Box,
  Button,
  Card,
  CardContent,
  Container,
  Typography,
} from '@material-ui/core';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import type { FC } from 'react';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet-async';
import Logo from 'src/components/Logo';
import axios from 'src/lib/axios';
import gtm from 'src/lib/gtm';

const Login: FC = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { isLoading, isAuthenticated, loginWithRedirect } = useAuth0();

  useEffect(() => {
    gtm.push({ event: 'page_view' });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isLoading && isAuthenticated) {
      router.push('/recommendations');
    }
  }, [isLoading, isAuthenticated]);

  const handleIntuitLogin = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('/auth/sign-in-with-intuit');
      window.location = response.data;
    } catch (e) {
      throw new Error(e);
    }
  };

  const handleAuth0Login = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('/auth/sign-in-with-auth0');
      window.location = response.data;
    } catch (e) {
      throw new Error(e);
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Helmet>
        <title>Login</title>
      </Helmet>
      <Box
        sx={{
          backgroundColor: 'background.default',
          display: 'flex',
          flexDirection: 'column',
          minHeight: '100vh',
        }}
      >
        <Container maxWidth="sm" sx={{ py: '80px' }}>
          <Box
            sx={{
              display: 'flex',
              justifyContent: 'center',
              mb: 8,
            }}
          >
            <Link href="/login">
              <Box>
                <Logo height={100} width={300} />
              </Box>
            </Link>
          </Box>
          <Card>
            <CardContent
              sx={{
                display: 'flex',
                flexDirection: 'column',
                p: 4,
              }}
            >
              <Box
                sx={{
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  display: 'flex',
                  justifyContent: 'space-between',
                  mb: 3,
                }}
              >
                <div>
                  <Typography
                    color="textPrimary"
                    gutterBottom
                    variant="h4"
                    data-testid="login-title"
                  >
                    Log in
                  </Typography>
                </div>
              </Box>
              <Box
                sx={{
                  flexGrow: 1,
                  mt: 3,
                }}
              >
                <Button
                  color="primary"
                  onClick={handleAuth0Login}
                  fullWidth
                  size="large"
                  type="button"
                  variant="contained"
                >
                  Sign In
                </Button>
              </Box>

              <Box sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
                <Button
                  color="primary"
                  onClick={handleIntuitLogin}
                  fullWidth
                  size="large"
                  type="button"
                  variant="contained"
                >
                  Sign In With Intuit
                </Button>
              </Box>
            </CardContent>
          </Card>
        </Container>
      </Box>
    </>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

EDIT 2:

RequireScope:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import useAuth from 'src/hooks/useAuth';

export interface RequireScopeProps {
  scopes: string[];
}

const RequireScope: React.FC<RequireScopeProps> = React.memo((props) => {
  const { children, scopes } = props;
  const { isInitialized, isAuthenticated, permissions } = useAuth();
  const [isPermitted, setIsPermitted] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated && isInitialized) {
      (async () => {
        const hasPermissions = scopes
          .map((s) => {
            return permissions.includes(s);
          })
          .filter(Boolean);

        if (hasPermissions.length === scopes.length) {
          setIsPermitted(true);
        }
      })();
    }
  }, [isAuthenticated, isInitialized, scopes, permissions]);

  if (isPermitted) {
    return <>{children}</>;
  }

  return null;
});

export default RequireScope;
```

Benchmarks.test.tsx

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { render, screen, waitFor, within } from '@testing-library/react';
import { HelmetProvider } from 'react-helmet-async';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import BenchmarksPage from '../src/pages/benchmarks/index';
import { initState } from './mockState'; // this is just an object with nested objects and arrays

test('renders header, timeframe dropdown and the chart image', async () => {
  const middlewares = [thunk];
  const mockStore = configureStore(middlewares);

  render(
    <HelmetProvider>
      <Provider store={mockStore(initState)}>
        <BenchmarksPage />
      </Provider>
    </HelmetProvider>,
  );

  // Note: NONE of these 5 queries below work. Component is not rendering in the DOM
  const header = screen.getByRole('heading', { name: /benchmarks/i });
  const header = screen.getByRole('heading');
  const header = await screen.findByRole('heading', { name: /benchmarks/i });
  const header = await waitFor(() => screen.getByText(/benchmarks/i));
  const header = await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getByText(/benchmarks/i)), {
    timeout: 4000,
  });

  screen.debug(); // doesn't work. <body></div></body>
}
```

EDIT3:

useAuth in RequireScope

```
import { useContext } from 'react';
import AuthContext from '../contexts/JWTContext';

const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);

export default useAuth;
```

JWTContext above:

Just really long, dispatches to /login using JWT token etc.

EDIT 4:
JWTContext component

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {
  createContext,
  FC,
  ReactNode,
  useCallback,
  useEffect,
  useReducer,
} from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'src/store';
import { companyActions } from 'src/store/company/company.slice';
import {
  getAllCompanies,
  getCurrentCompany,
} from 'src/store/company/company.thunk';
import axios from '../lib/axios';

export interface AuthUser {
  sub?: string;
  nickname?: string;
  email?: string;
  name?: string;
  picture?: string;
  locale?: string;
  updated_at?: Date;
}
interface State {
  isInitialized: boolean;
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
  permissions: string[];
  user: AuthUser;
}

interface AuthContextValue extends State {
  platform: 'JWT';
  login: () => Promise<void>;
  logout: () => Promise<void>;
}

interface AuthProviderProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

type InitializeAction = {
  type: 'INITIALIZE';
  payload: {
    isAuthenticated: boolean;
    permissions: string[];
    user: AuthUser;
  };
};

type LoginAction = {
  type: 'LOGIN';
};

type LogoutAction = {
  type: 'LOGOUT';
};
type Action = InitializeAction | LoginAction | LogoutAction;

const initialState: State = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  isInitialized: false,
  permissions: [],
  user: undefined,
};

const setSession = (
  accessToken?: string,
  permissions?: string,
  user?: string,
): void => {
  if (accessToken && permissions) {
    localStorage.setItem('accessToken', accessToken);
    localStorage.setItem('perms', permissions);
    localStorage.setItem('user', user);

    //axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
  } else {
    localStorage.removeItem('accessToken');
    localStorage.removeItem('perms');
    localStorage.removeItem('user');
    //delete axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization;
  }
};

const handlers: Record<string, (state: State, action: Action) => State> = {
  INITIALIZE: (state: State, action: InitializeAction): State => {
    const { isAuthenticated, permissions, user } = action.payload;

    return {
      ...state,
      isAuthenticated,
      isInitialized: true,
      permissions,
      user,
    };
  },
  LOGIN: (state: State): State => {
    return {
      ...state,
      isAuthenticated: true,
    };
  },
  LOGOUT: (state: State): State => ({
    ...state,
    isAuthenticated: false,
    permissions: [],
  }),
};

const reducer = (state: State, action: Action): State =>
  handlers[action.type] ? handlers[action.type](state, action) : state;

const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextValue>({
  ...initialState,
  platform: 'JWT',
  login: () => Promise.resolve(),
  logout: () => Promise.resolve(),
});

export const AuthProvider: FC<AuthProviderProps> = (props) => {
  const { children } = props;
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  const router = useRouter();
  const reduxDispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    const initialize = async (): Promise<void> => {
      try {
        if (router.isReady) {
          const { token, permissions, user, companyId } = router.query;

          // TODO: Move all of this stuff from query and localstorage into session
          const accessToken =
            (token as string) || window.localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
          const permsStorage = window.localStorage.getItem('perms');
          const perms = (permissions as string) || permsStorage;
          const userStorage = window.localStorage.getItem('user');
          const selectedCompanyId =
            (companyId as string) || window.localStorage.getItem('companyId');
          const authUser = (user as string) || userStorage;

          if (accessToken && perms) {
            setSession(accessToken, perms, authUser);

            try {
              // check if user is admin by this perm, probably want to add a flag later
              if (perms.includes('create:calcs')) {
                if (!selectedCompanyId) {
                  const response = await reduxDispatch(getAllCompanies());

                  const companyId = response.payload[0].id;
                  reduxDispatch(companyActions.selectCompany(companyId));
                  reduxDispatch(getCurrentCompany({ companyId }));
                } else {
                  reduxDispatch(
                    companyActions.selectCompany(selectedCompanyId),
                  );
                  await reduxDispatch(
                    getCurrentCompany({ companyId: selectedCompanyId }),
                  );
                }
              } else {
                reduxDispatch(companyActions.selectCompany(selectedCompanyId));
                await reduxDispatch(
                  getCurrentCompany({ companyId: selectedCompanyId }),
                );
              }
            } catch (e) {
              console.warn(e);
            } finally {
              dispatch({
                type: 'INITIALIZE',
                payload: {
                  isAuthenticated: true,
                  permissions: JSON.parse(perms),
                  user: JSON.parse(authUser),
                },
              });
            }

            if (token || permissions) {
              router.replace(router.pathname, undefined, { shallow: true });
            }
          } else {
            dispatch({
              type: 'INITIALIZE',
              payload: {
                isAuthenticated: false,
                permissions: [],
                user: undefined,
              },
            });
            setSession(undefined);

            if (router.pathname !== '/client-landing') {
              router.push('/login');
            }
          }
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        dispatch({
          type: 'INITIALIZE',
          payload: {
            isAuthenticated: false,
            permissions: [],
            user: undefined,
          },
        });
        //router.push('/login');
      }
    };

    initialize();
  }, [router.isReady]);

  const login = useCallback(async (): Promise<void> => {
    const response = await axios.get('/auth/sign-in-with-intuit');
    window.location = response.data;
  }, []);

  const logout = useCallback(async (): Promise<void> => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');

    // only logout if already logged in
    if (token) {
      dispatch({ type: 'LOGOUT' });
    }

    setSession(null);

    router.push('/login');
  }, [dispatch, router]);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        ...state,
        platform: 'JWT',
        login,
        logout,
      }}
    >
      {state.isInitialized && children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

AuthProvider.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
};

export default AuthContext;
```

When I render a component by wrapping it with AuthProvider, I get the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'isReady' of null

      217 |
      218 |     initialize();
    > 219 |   }, [router.isReady]);
```

I searched the whole day how to make the router not to be null, but I could not.

If there are any other suggestions on how to simulate a logged in user given the code above, I would greatly appreciate it. THank you.

Comment: What happens in the `RequireScope` component? Can you share the code for that too?

Comment: @juliomalves absolutely. Please see EDIT2. Thanks a bunch

Comment: That's probably the culprit. You need to simulate a logged-in user in your test so that `isPermitted` is true and the component displays the children passed to it.

Comment: @juliomalves Hello, I tried to simulate a logged in user but failed because router is null when I run the AuthProvider component(this wraps the component to be rendered in Jest). If you know how to fix nextjs router being null, or have other suggestions on how to simulate a logged in user given the code above, please let me know. 

Please see EDIT4. AuthProvider wraps the whole app. AuthContext send the object to RequireScope that will allow us to set 'isPermitted' to true.  I would greatly appreciate your help one last time. Please see EDIT2,3,4. Thanks